# Which progressions and sequences are guaranteed to contain infinitely many primes?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

**Progressions.** Dirichlet famously proved that, if $a$ and $b$ are coprime integers, the arithmetic progression $a+db$ (*i.e.,* with $d=1,2,3,\dots$) contains infinitely many prime numbers. Are there any other such results? I believe there are no analogous quadratic or higher-power sequences, but I could have missed some.

**Sequences.** Other than the obvious/trivial ones (or arithmetic progressions, covered above), which number sequences [with a regular algebraic definition] contain infinitely many prime numbers?

Comment: You can construct infinitely many such sequences. OEIS contains some of the interesting ones.

Comment: @daniel: Do you have any specific references? I've only found trivial ones (_e.g.,_ Sophie Germain primes <https://oeis.org/A005384>), or ones using functions like floor (_e.g.,_ https://oeis.org/A132222). I'm hoping for sequences/progressions with simpler definitions, like Dirichlet's.